# Semi-definite positive matrix sum up to identity in diagonal is greater than a changed form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

In physics we use a set of semi-definite positive matrices to describe quantum measurement, they should satisfy $\sum_i \Pi_i=\mathbb I,\Pi_i\ge0\,\forall i$. I wonder if there are some way to show that $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
\Pi_{1} & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & \Pi_{2} & \ldots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \Pi_{M}
\end{array}\right) \geq\left(\begin{array}{c}
\Pi_{1} \\
\Pi_{2} \\
\vdots \\
\Pi_{M}
\end{array}\right)\left(\Pi_{1} \Pi_{2} \ldots \Pi_{M}\right).$$ where $A\ge B$ means $A-B$ is a semi-definite positive matrix.

I try to figure out when $\Pi_i$ are real positive numbers sum up to $1$, which can be proved but for $\Pi_i$ stand for semi-definite matrices, I don't know where to go.

Any suggestion or hint will be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The inequality is related to positive definitness ?

Comment: @P.Quinton Yes, the inequality $A\ge B$ means $A-B$ is semi-definite positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Denote by $X^\ast$ the conjugate transpose of a matrix $X$. Let
$$
D=\pmatrix{
\Pi_1\\
&\Pi_2\\
&&\ddots\\
&&&&\Pi_M}
,\ E=\pmatrix{I\\ I\\ \vdots\\ I}.
$$
The difference between the two sides of your inequality is then
$$
D-DEE^\ast D=D^{1/2}(I-P)D^{1/2}\tag{1}
$$
where $P=D^{1/2}EE^\ast D^{1/2}$. Since $P^\ast=P$ and
$$
P^2=D^{1/2}E(E^\ast DE)E^\ast D^{1/2}=D^{1/2}E(I)E^\ast D^{1/2}=P,
$$
we see that $P$ is an orthogonal projection. Hence $I-P\ge0$ and by $(1)$, $D-DEE^\ast D$ is positive semidefinite too.